# When I apply a Dreamweaver template to an HTML file, nothing happens

Tags: dreamweaver

When I apply a Dreamweaver template (MainTemplate.dwt) to a page (ContactMe.html), absolutely nothing happens. I used the `Modify > Templates > Apply Template To Page...` when in my ContactMe.html page. I've tried doing this earlier today, and it worked as expected. However, it stopped working for me just now. Any ideas?

Also, sometimes I get a random "Error while accessing file. File not found (error code -43)". But the file is where it says it is...

Answer (score 0):

I think the DWT got corrupted somehow with bad markup. In any case, I created the template again from scratch, and now it seems to work!